# Inequality using the Mean Value theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

(H.A Priestley - Introduction to Integration - Exercise 2.10)

> Let $ 0\lt \alpha\lt 1 $ and define $f(x) := \alpha x - x^\alpha$. 
>
> Show that $f(x) \ge f(1) \  \forall x \ge 0$ 
>
>
> Hence show that $$ a^\alpha b ^{1-\alpha} \le \alpha a +(1-\alpha)b \ \ \forall a,b \ge 0$$

The first part is obvious through the mean value theorem:

$f'(x) = \alpha-(\alpha)x^{\alpha-1}=\alpha(1-x^{\alpha-1})$ which with the condition on $\alpha$ is $\ge 0$ if $0 \lt x \le 1$ and negative if $x>1$
and therefore $f(x)-f(1)=(x-1)f'(\eta)$ is always $\ge0$

However I am stuck on the second part !

I have tried applying the inequality to $a^\alpha$ and $b^{1-\alpha}$ to give

$$\alpha a -a^{\alpha} \ge \alpha -1$$
$$a^{\alpha} \le \alpha a +1-\alpha$$ and so
$$b^{1-\alpha} \le (1-\alpha) b +\alpha$$ 
but then I am not sure ...

Comment: Clearly $f(1) = \alpha - 1$ and hence $f(a/b) \geq f(1)$ so that $\alpha(a/b) - a^{\alpha}/b^{\alpha} \geq \alpha - 1$ or $\alpha a + (1 - \alpha)b \geq a^{\alpha}b^{1 - \alpha}$

Comment: Yes of course , I need to apply the inequality to f (a/b ) ! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by user Paramanand Singh,  simply apply the inequality to $f(a/b)$

Comment: Its not good to post an answer just based on the ideas of others, if you don't make your answers Community Wiki.

Comment: now done sorry I did not know